# How to specify language of website? (HTML?)

Tags: html

How do I specify that a page is in a certain language so search engines can understand?

Is it a meta tag I put at the top? If it is, do you know if most of the search engines use this to determine language?

I have converted 1 page of content in english to several different languages, and would like to include that information in the html/let the search engines know which language they are dealing with.

Answer (score 19):

Quick google search gave me this: [HTTP and meta for language](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-http-and-lang).  tl;dr

```
<html lang="en">
```

There are other ways of specifying.  If you are using apache, you can use a file extension for apache to pull the correct version based on the user-agent's given preferences.  for example, name your index page `index.html.en`, `index.html.jp`, `index.html.de` and so on...

Answer (score 15):

Depending on your dtd:

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
```

XHTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

If you are using a right to left language:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="he" lang="he" dir="rtl">
```

If using XHTML, you'll want to specify both the xml:lang and lang attributes. The xml:lang attribute takes precedence over lang.

Answer (score 8):

Check this page for a range of things you can do to try to get the search engine to pick up the right language.

[How to Specify an HTML Web Document Language for good SEO](http://www.antezeta.com/blog/document-language)

(In no particular order)

1. right domain suffix
2. hosted in right county
3. AddHeading syntax (Apache)
4. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="yourlanguage" />`
5. `<html lang="yourlanguage">` for xhtml `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="yourlanguage" lang="yourlanguage">`
6. `<p lang="yourlanguage">`
7. `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content= "text/html; yourcharset">`
8. And search engines to text pattern analysis too (prefix/suffix of words, n-grams analysis)