# Proper way to add the language tag in Next/Head

Tags: html, next.js, head

I cannot find a solid example of using the language tag with Next Head. Here are the two best I've seen. Which one, if either, is proper?

Note: It doesnt have to be dynamic.

Option 1

```
<Head>
  <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
  ...
</Head>
```

Option 2

```
<html lang='en'>
  <Head>
  ...
  </Head>
</html>
```

Option 3 (capital Html)

```
<Html lang='en'>
  <Head>
  ...
  </Head>
</Html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify language of website? (HTML?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071789/how-to-specify-language-of-website-html)

Comment: Does this answer your question: [NextJS html \[lang\] missing by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66737700/1870780)? Add it in your custom `_document` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to the next.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en-US'],
    defaultLocale: 'en-US',
    localeDetection: false,
  },
}
```